# What are the proper terms for highly-educated people?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, modern-life

I'm curious about terms that can be used to describe these people, or the qualifications themselves:

1. College/university graduate
2. Somebody with a "Master's" qualification
3. Somebody with a "Doctorate" qualification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good general word for someone who has graduated from a school is *alumnus*.
It has the added benefit that the same word is used in a number of languages and is easy to recognize.

A useful phrase in this context is also *titulus academicus*, an academic title.
If you say *ille magister est*, it is unclear whether he is a teacher or a master.
If you mean the latter, you can say *titulum academicum magistri habet*.
This allows you to specify what you mean.

There are several ways you can translate "degree".
In analogy to Italian, *laurea* is an option.
Vicipaedia uses *gradus academicus*, which is a good choice.
One option is to go with *diploma* (neuter!) and pair it with a suitable adjective.

You can translate "doctorate" as *doctoratus* and similarly *magistratus* for masters.
The latter has an established meaning, but that should not interfere if the context is clear enough in context.

Comment: No mention of *baccalaureus*?

Comment: @Figulus No, for two reasons: The original question did not include bachelor's degrees (which I believe *baccalaureus* would correspond to), and I couldn't find the word in the sources I'd prefer. It seems that in Finland we call bachelors *candidati* due to the word used in Finnish and Swedish. But if you have something to say about that word, I'd be happy to vote up a second answer!